# Get worker name from multisession framework provided by future package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future

I am  parallelizing the data analysis via multiplesession plan of future package. The dataset is large.  I tried to let each worker return the model fitting output to the main R session, and write the results collectively to the hard drive.  But the outputs are large, and consume huge memories.  So I am trying to let each worker to write the output individually to the hard drive.  But in this way, the work name or ID is necessary, otherwise different workers could write to the same file and mess it up.

Here is my current code:

```
plan(multisession, workers = 4)

model_out <-
  # Column names for CpG meth
  str_subset(colnames(m_demm), "^cg") |>
  # Set names that will be incorporated into the output
  set_names() |>
  future_map(
    # Build formula
    ~ str_c("dementia_ages1_eos ~ ", .x, " + a1age + sex") %>%
      # Convert string to formula. It is necessary for `tidy()` to work.
      as.formula() %>%
      # Run the model
      multinom(data = m_demm) %>%
      # Tidy output
      # Has to be this way. A bare `tidy()` incurs an error of no applicable method for
      # lm class object.
      broom:::tidy.multinom() |>
      # Remove parentheses from "(Intercept)", and var name from dementia categories
      modify_at("term", ~ str_remove_all(.x, "dementia_ages1_eos|\\)|\\("))
  ) |>
  list_rbind(names_to = "cg")
```

I found a similar post, [R - get worker name when running in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053763/r-get-worker-name-when-running-in-parallel).  But it only provides a suggestion for parallel package.

Answer (score 0):

The `base::Sys.info()` function has information about the current system, including hostname and username.  The `base::Sys.pid()` function provides the process ID of the current R process.  Since process IDs may be reused, especially on MS Windows, you probably also want to add another identifier to make your information unique, e.g. the current time.

So, you can create an identifier that is unique to each R process by doing something like:

```
> key <- list(host = Sys.info()[["nodename"]], user = Sys.info()[["user"]], pid = Sys.getpid(), time = Sys.time())
> hash <- digest::digest(key)
> hash
[1] "134616e6e4eb41df810d34c179b0764c"
```

An alternative is to use the input data for each iteration as the `key` object; that way you'll get the same `key` whenever you pass the exact same input. You could then even skip the processing if the result file already exists. This is strategy is referred to as "memoization".

Comment: I did not try the alternative way since my data are large; it would take quite long to generate the hash.  Hope *future* package will provide the functionality for writing out results from workers.

Comment: Re: "Hope future package will provide the functionality for writing out results from workers".  From a future's point of view, there's not really a concept of a worker. This is by design. It should be possible to resolve a future expression anywhere.  We could talk about R sessions though; it would be nice if R had a built-in `sessionId()` that we could all rely on instead of writing our own (as above).

Answer (score 0):

Based on *HenrikB's* answer, I figured out the following code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(furrr)

iris |>
  split(f = iris$Species) |>
  future_walk(function(x) {
    # Generate filename
    filename <-
      list(
        host = Sys.info()[["nodename"]],
        user = Sys.info()[["user"]],
        pid = Sys.getpid(),
        time = Sys.time()
      ) %>%
      digest::digest()
    # Write modelling results
    lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, data = x) %>%
      broom:::tidy.lm() %>%
      write_csv(str_c("/full/path/to/the/folder/", filename, ".csv"))
  })
```

Two points needs special attention:

1. Bare `tidy()` or even `broom::tidy()` don't work.
2. The full path of the folder you want to save your file is required.